# Graphing problems with a symfun

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

Currently writing a symfun with one input and three outputs. The equation is 
`exp(x) -3*x.^2 +1`. Input is `x` and the outputs are the equation itself (denoted by `f`), its first derivative (denoted by `fp`) and the second derivative (denoted by `fpp`). Trying to plot these three graphs on the interval `[-5 5]`. I am using `fplot(fun[-5 5]);`. The only graph shown is `exp(x) -3*x.^2 +1`. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you post what you've tried using code block formatting to make it more clear what you're trying?

Comment: @jodag edited hope its clearer.

Comment: For plotting three graphs of three functions f1, f2, f3, use: `fplot(f1,[-5 5]);hold on;fplot(f2,[-5 5]);hold on;fplot(f3,[-5 5]);hold on;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a code for that (no need for `hold`):

```
syms x
f = symfun(exp(x) -3*x.^2 +1,x);
fp = diff(f);
fpp = diff(fp);
fplot([f,fp,fpp],[-5 5])
legend({char(f),char(fp),char(fpp)})
```

you need to put all functions in a vector (i.e. `[f,fp,fpp]`).

The output:

[image: flpot]

Comment: Undefined function or variable. Trying to write it in a way that the plotting is in a script and everything up to and including the fpp is in a function so that I can use the function again later on.

Comment: When I run just this, without writing anything else I get the plot and no error, so try to be more specific about the error you get. Run this line by line, and see which line causing the problem

Comment: Currently using a function with the following text.

    sym x
    f= (exp(x) -3*x.^2 +1,x);
    fp= diff(f);
    fpp= diff(fp)

This works perfectly.
Then I have a script file containing the following 

    fplot([f,fp,fpp],[-5 5]
The error message that appears is 

    undefined function or variable f
    error in script
    fplot([f,fp,fpp],[-5 5])

Comment: If you want to use the functions `f`, `fp` and `fpp` inside another function then you need to pass it as input, you can't just have it in the workspace. This should be something like: `plot_ffpfpp (f,fp,fpp)` where `plot_ffpfpp` is your function name

Comment: So `plot_fun(f,fp,fpp)`? Is this put into the function or the script?

Comment: say you have a function`fun` that define `f,fp,fpp` and now you want to use this functions (`f,fp,fpp`) in a script outside `fun`, then you must pass it as output from `fun` so the first line in `fun` will be: `[f,fp,fpp] = fun (some input)`, then you can write in your script: `[f,fp,fpp] = fun (some input)`, and after this: `fplot([f,fp,fpp],[-5 5])`, and it will work